# Unable to find syscall_table_32.S file in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, archlinux

I am using the `linux-headers-2.6.32-21` package on Virtual Machine. I am going to write a new system call. I have found the other files to write initials of system calls but I am unable to find this `syscall_table_32.S` in `arch/x86/kernel/` directory. Please help me how and where I can find this file. I am doubted that it might be hidden due to permission issues or others.

Answer (score 3):

The following commit removes it:

```
commit 303395ac3bf3e2cb488435537d416bc840438fcb
Author: H. Peter Anvin <hpa@linux.intel.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 16:07:41 2011 -0800

    x86: Generate system call tables and unistd_*.h from tables

    Generate system call tables and unistd_*.h automatically from the
    tables in arch/x86/syscalls.  All other information, like NR_syscalls,
    is auto-generated, some of which is in asm-offsets_*.c.

    This allows us to keep all the system call information in one place,
    and allows for kernel space and user space to see different
    information; this is currently used for the ia32 system call numbers
    when building the 64-bit kernel, but will be used by the x32 ABI in
    the near future.

    This also removes some gratuitious differences between i386, x86-64
    and ia32; in particular, now all system call tables are generated with
    the same mechanism.
```

because now syscall table is generated by the script arch/x86/syscalls/syscalltbl.sh, based on arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_{32,64}.tbl.

Comment: Sorry @Cong Wang ,  I did not get you. Please guide me simply where I can find the syscall_table_32.S file to place my code. :(

Comment: Where is it hard to understand?  syscall_table_32.S is REMOVED, patch arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_{32,64}.tbl if you need.

Comment: there is no folder syscalls/ in x86/ directory. :(

Comment: % ls arch/x86/syscalls
Makefile  syscall_32.tbl  syscall_64.tbl  syscallhdr.sh  syscalltbl.sh

Comment: I have no syscalls folder in x86.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/src/kernels/3.3.4-5.fc17.i686.PAE/arch/x86/include/generated/asm

here you can get the syscalls_32.h.