# syscall_table_32.S not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, system-calls

Downloaded `linux-3.7.8` source. Trying to add system call to it.

Surprisingly I couldn't find `arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S`. After some googling I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534013/unable-to-find-syscall-table-32-s-file-in-linux). He says `syscall_table_32.S is REMOVED, because now syscall table is generated by the script arch/x86/syscalls/syscalltbl.sh, based on arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_{32,64}.tbl.`

```
 Now, How do I add my own system call ??
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, After googling for a while I got a nice tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rr_VoQCOgE), explains `How to add a System Call to Kernel 3.3.8`